# Table-valued parameters with Entity Framework stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I am using EF 6.0 and have a stored procedure with 3 table-valued parameters (input) as read-only. When I try to execute the stored procedure using this C# code:

```
DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC SP", new SqlParameter("TVP1", SqlDbType.Structured) { Value = SaomeValue1 }, new SqlParameter("TVP2", SqlDbType.Structured) { Value = SaomeValue2 }, new SqlParameter("TVP3", SqlDbType.Structured) { Value = SaomeValue3 });
```

`SomeValue1/2/3` being the domain objects (`ICollection<T>`)

I get this error

> Failed to convert parameter value from a List`1 to a IEnumerable`1

Hence I tried to code a class `T1Collection` as below

```
public class T1Collection : List<T1>, IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>
{
    IEnumerator<SqlDataRecord> IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        var sqlRow = new SqlDataRecord(
              new SqlMetaData("P1", SqlDbType.Int),
              new SqlMetaData("P2", SqlDbType.BigInt));

        foreach (var v in this)
        {
            sqlRow.SetInt32(0, v.P1);
            sqlRow.SetInt64(1, v.P2);
            yield return sqlRow;
        }
    }
}
```

However I still have the same error.

Can someone please help me what I am doing wrong here?